# Determination of depth level effectively for a node using cytoscape.js algorithms

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am currently trying to render a functionality to make only nodes and edges visible only when the node has minimum depth value.Can you please let me know how to find node's depth effectively as Breadth-first /Depth-first search makes to iterate thru each node and its successors at each depth level to determine the depth value.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question.  Use `eles.bfs()` or `eles.dfs()` and use the `depth` provided to the visitor function.